# Where are good examples of Web applications built for skilled and intense use?

Tags: user-interface

I have spent most of my development career writing backend code, or front-end apps for used as daily business tools, by at least semi-skilled staff, e.g. order-tracking, sales capture, etc.  That those I helped build peformed their tasks well is comfort enough, but I am still seeking excellence in the building of these kind of apps, versus the trendy emphasis on more personal relationships with the UI.

Can anyone recommend reading on this type of application (LOB?) on the web today?  Any available examples to study?

Comment: This sounds like "bucking the trend" for the sake of doing so rather than for any particular reason. The condescending "emphasis on slow and sensual interpersonal relationships with the UI" points in that direction.

Comment: @Adam, I imagine bank tellers, their clients, and their managers, all prefer a quicker, more mechanical user experience for repetitive business transactions.

Although it would be nice if corporate training could be evolved to leaving a user alone with their workstation for a morning, to meld and get to know each other.

Comment: Reducing a human to a mechanical operator to a machine misses the point. The point of the UI is to take the machine to the person so that they can carry out their jobs easily. Not the other way round.

Comment: You're missing my point.  Very often, and widely, the operator is already reduced to a machine.  I'll leave it to more Quixotic individuals to change the world, and concentrate on making the interface better for the 'machine operators' and their keepers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you read [Don't Make me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789723107). Don't think that engaging UIs are not efficient. I would suggest the opposite.

Actually [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393597/book-recommendations-web-usability/549216#549216) has many useful links.

Comment: I'm sure many more engaging, and better designed UI's can improve effiency, I was just refering to the de-emphasis of 'industrial' efficiency in current trending topics.

Comment: Can you put some examples in your question please. I'd like to know more as where/if it exists.